# Azure pipeline parameter reference with dynamic keys

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Within an Azure pipeline .yml file I have this line:

```
variables:
 - group: WebAppDevelopment_2023
```

This works fine.

To prevent repetition i have an loop:

```
- ${{ each stage in parameters.environmentsGates }}:
  - stage:
    displayName: Publish DEVELOPMENT build to development environment
    variables:
    - group: WebAppDevelopment_2023
```

There is also:

```
 parameters:
  - name: 'variableGroups'
    type: object
    default:
      - Development: 'WebbDevelopment_2023'
      - UAT: 'UAT_2032'
      - Production: 'ProdEnv'
  - name: 'environmentsGates'
    type: object
    default: 
      - environmentName: Development
        # other key/values
      - environmentName: UAT
        # other key/values
      - environmentName: Production
        # other key/values
```

My question is:

On each iteration of the loop i have a different value for `stage.environmentName` and that should be the key for `parameters.variableGroups`. Example below

```
variables:
    - group: ${{parameters.variableGroups[${{stage.environmentName}}].value}}
```

How do I get this working, I have tried many combinations macro, runtime, etc syntax but no success

I've experimented with conditionals, again without success: E.g.

```
    variables:
        - ${{each group in parameters.variableGroups}}:
            - ${{ if eq(group.Value,  '${{stage.environmentName}}')}}:
                  - group: ${{group.Value}}
              ${{ else }}:
                  - group: WebAppDevelopment_2023
        - name: token
          value: $(azure-deploy-token)
```

Returns error:

```
Unexpected state while attempting to read the mapping end. State:

MappingState:
  IsStart: True
  Index: 0
  IsKey: False
  IsEnd: False

SequenceState:
  IsStart: False
  Index: 0
  IsEnd: False

EachExpressionState:
  IsSequenceInsertion: True
  IsStart: False
  Index: 1
  IsEnd: False

MappingState:
  IsStart: False
  Index: 0
  IsKey: True
  IsEnd: False

SequenceState:
  IsStart: False
  Index: 0
  IsEnd:[...]
```

Comment: Do you really have so many environments that it's worth implementing in a loop? You know it is possible to parameterise too much. You also might find eventually that individual environments may need a slight tweak to the code which is not supported by templating

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I know what you mean. In this case I have multiple static sites and a static site generator ( the sites all have life span of 12 months). The pipeline code that this is from is part of the template set up that include default ways of working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified your case but it works here in this way

```
parameters:
  - name: 'variableGroups'
    type: object
    default:
      - key : Development
        name : 'WebbDevelopment_2023'
      - key : UAT
        name: 'UAT_2032'
      - key: Production
        name : 'ProdEnv'
  - name: 'environmentsGates'
    type: object
    default: 
      - environmentName: Development
      - environmentName: UAT
      - environmentName: Production

trigger:
- grog
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps: 
- ${{ each stage in parameters.environmentsGates }}:
  - ${{ each varg in parameters.variableGroups }}:
      ${{ if eq(varg.key, stage.environmentName) }}: 
        script: |
            echo '${{ stage.environmentName }}'
            echo '${{ varg.name }}'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I was trying too hard to avoid adding another loop. Thought there would be a more 'javascript-y` way

Comment: Yeah. But I couldn't find a better way. @user3067684 could you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful?